# button delete do not remove product

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I try to include a delete button with a javascript message. When I click on the trash, I have a message appear to confirm the action. But if I have 3 products, the message appears 3 times, 2 products, 2 times.
Also, the product is not deleted after click on the confirm button.

Thank you

```
           $form = HTML::form('cart_quantity', CLICSHOPPING::link(null, 'Cart&Update'), 'post', 'role="form" id="cart_quantity"', ['tokenize' => true]);

           for ($i=0, $n=count($products); $i<$n; $i++) {
              $products_name_url = $this->getProductsUrlRewrited()->getProductNameUrl($this->getProductID($products[$i]['id']));

              $products_name = HTML::hiddenField('products_id[]', $products[$i]['id']);
              $products_name .= HTML::link($products_name_url, $products[$i]['name']);

    //no message
    //          $trash = HTML::link($this->link(null, 'Cart&Delete&products_id=' . $products[$i]['id']), '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>', 'alt="' . $this->getDef('button_remove')) . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; ==> works fine but no message



    //with message
              $remove_product = ['params' => 'id="remove_product' . $products[$i]['id'] .'"'];
              $trash = HTML::link($this->link(null, 'Cart&Delete&products_id=' . $products[$i]['id']), HTML::button(null, 'fas fa-trash',null, null, $remove_product)) . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';


              $test = 'remove_product' . $products[$i]['id'];
              $trash .= '<script>
    var $button = $(\'#'. $test . '\')
    $(function() {
      $button.click(function () {
        $(\'form\').submit(function () {
          if (!window.confirm(\'Are you sure?\')) return false
        })
      })
    })
    </script>         
    ';
    }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: The logic is inverse, should be: `if confirm, then form submit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the problem you have that any clicked button trigger events, as many times as there are buttons in sub DOM element. So What you need to do as to get an exact element what trigger the event:

```
//with message
$product_id = 'remove_product' . $products[$i]['id'];
$remove_product = ['params' => 'id="'. $product_id .'"'];
$trash = HTML::link($this->link(null, 'Cart&Delete&products_id=' . $products[$i]['id']), HTML::button(null, 'fas fa-trash',null, null, $remove_product)) . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';


$but_id = $product_id;
echo "<script>
    var button = $('#". $but_id . "');
    $(document).on('click', button, function (event) {
        console.log('button clicked');
        //$('form').submit(function () {
          //if (!window.confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;
        //})
    })
    </script>         
    ";
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(e){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <button id="product_delete1" data-id="1">Delete</button>
    <button id="product_delete2" data-id="2">Delete</button>
    <button id="product_delete3" data-id="3">Delete</button>
</form>
```